# HELM 3: Helm test is not working? Getting "TEST SUITE: None"

Tags: testing, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Preview:
We started working on helm 3 to deploy our applications on k8s and we have come to good stage with deploying the charts successfully. However we are very new to implement tests under helm charts.
For example I am deploying pdfreactor official image and i can check the web application version details either by using browser "http://172.27.1.119:31423/service/" or by "curl [http://172.27.1.119:31423/service/"](http://172.27.1.119:31423/service/%22). Now I want to write a helm test to check the same. The below is pdfreactor-test.yaml (reference link: https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_tests/)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-credentials-test"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: {{ .Release.Name }}-credentials-test
      image: {{ .Values.image.imageName }}
      imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy | quote }}
      command:
        - /bin/bash
        - curl http://172.27.1.119:31423/service/
```

When i ran

```
 helm install pdfreactor <chart name> 
 helm test pdfreactor
```

I got below response

```
NAME: pdfreactor
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Aug 13 09:02:55 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
Thank you for installing pdfreactor.
```

Below are my challenges.

1. Need to understand what am i doing wrong?
2. How exactly the helm test will work? Does it create a new pod and test, or does it test on existing pod?
3. What is the purpose of giving image details in test.yaml?

Note: I have even used the default template generated with helm create.

Comment: I found the solution to this while seeing that I introduced this problem. For me, it was an entry in .helmignore of that chart that unintentionally ignored the helm tests meant to validate it. removing that entry or modifying it not ignore the helm test I wanted to run made it run correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your test configuration files reside under `<chart-name>/templates/tests/` folder.

Regarding 2 and 3 - Yes, it creates a new pod, using the template you provided. The pod will run to completion, and if the Exit Code will be 0, the test is considered successful.

Comment: Hi,   I have done exactly as you said, the problem is the test suit is not being identified.

Comment: Can you please share your chart folder structure?

Comment: fodler structure as below (I am not using ingress)                                                                                 ` pdfreactor
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   ├── NOTES.txt
│   ├── service.yaml
│   └── tests
│       └── test-connection.yaml
└── values.yaml `

Comment: sorry.. Not able to put tree output properly, 1.   Inside pdfreactor chart i have "Chart.yaml  templates  values.yaml". 2. inside templates "deployment.yaml  _helpers.tpl  NOTES.txt  service.yaml  tests". 3. inside tests " test-connection.yaml"

Comment: OK. Can you please share your `helm version`? Thanks.

Comment: Version:"v3.1.0"

Answer (score 1):

You can only test what was templated at the last install time. If you are writing a new test you need to upgrade the chart, or uninstall and re-install, to run it.

Comment: I am following the same steps,  I do the helm install of chart then run helm test.  I have given the steps which i followed in question